# Spring MVC - Session differences

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, servlets, httpsession

Are there any differences between getting session through `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` and `HttpSession` injected in controller's method?

Comment: i believe both are same :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically there is no diffrerence between the `session` object injected into a *Spring MVC* controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/somepath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse someMethod (HttpSession session)
{
 // play with session attributes
}
```

And the `session` object retrieved from the `HttpServletRequest`:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/somepath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse someMethod (HttpServletRequest request)
{
  Session session = request.getSession();
  // You are playin with the same session attributes.
}
```

The former style just provide you with a facility to get the contextual `HttpSession` object by injecting it as a controller argument so that *Spring* takes care of the all the dirty stuff for you.