# Difference between HttpServletRequest.getSession(false) and HttpSession

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session-variables

I am working in an Spring MVC project, where to get values from session we have used..

```
session = request.getSession(false);
Object obj = (Object) session.getAttribute("sessionVeriable");
```

Where as `request` is `HttpServletRequest` class object passed from controller.

My point is why `HttpServletRequest` object is passed why not `HttpSession` directly. Is there any difference getting session object from HttpServletRequest and directly from HttpSession?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC - Session differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873446/spring-mvc-session-differences)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`session = request.getSession(false);` returns a session only if there is one associated with the request. E.g. a RESTful application would most certainly work without sessions. That in turn means that the code you provided could theoretically throw a `NullPointerException`.

Having a `HttpSession` instance passed to a method means that a session will be created if none is already associated with the request. If the `request` parameter is not used for something else it's the better choice in your case.

For the sake of completeness: `session = request.getSession();` would effectively be the same as  having a `HttpSession` parameter.